# Creating a modal within Bootstrap and Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working on a web app using bootstrap and angular.  I have a button that I would like to show a modal with data from another html page (employee.function.add.html).  All files are under the root employee folder

Here is the modal content within employee.function.add.html

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                  <h1>Lab 6</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                      Employee Information
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Title:</div>
                        <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="title"></div>
                        <div class="text-right col-xs-2">First:</div>
                        <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="firstname"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Phone#</div>
                        <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="phone"></div>
                        <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Email</div>
                        <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="email"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-right col-xs-2">Dept:</div>
                        <div class="text-left col-xs-3" id="departmentname"></div>
                        <div class="text-left col-xs-2">Surname:</div>
                        <div class="text-left col-xs-4">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="enter last name" id="TextBoxLastName" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                      <input type="button" value="Find Employee" id="empbutton" />
                      <div class="col-xs-10" id="lblstatus"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The button is created within employee.function.html here

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
  <div class="row">
    <!--<div class="col-md-6">-->
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#e0e9f5">
                <h2 class="panel-title">Employee Functions</h2>
              </div> 
              <br />
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div align="right" style="padding-bottom:10px">
                    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-default btn-lg" href="employee.function.add.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">Add Function</button>-->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
                </div>              
                </div>      
              <div class="panel-body">
                <jqxGrid 
                  [width]="'100%'" [theme]='"energyblue"' [source]='functionAdapter' [pageable]='true' [height]='500' [altrows]='true'
                  [editable]='true' [columns]='columns'>
               </jqxGrid>
              </div>

            </div>         
        </div>  
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/.col-->
  </div>
  <!--/.row-->
</div>
```

I keep getting this error in the console.

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's Javascript requires Jquery
```

In the index.html file I already declared all the needed styles and links for bootstrap.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

How can I get the modal to work?
and would like something clarified.  I am using bootstrap and angular for the project. Within the employee folder and the other folders are html files and ts files.  Am I getting this error because I should write the modal using angular? and not bootstrap?  I assumed I would make the modal using bootstrap, but that error appears.  Some clarification would be helpful.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: which version of angular?

Comment: It says it requires jQuery but you don't show us where you actually included jQuery so my guess is you're missing jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to add jQuery to your project. Bootstrap needs jQuery in order to work. Add this line to your code before including bootstrap.min.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope that helps! :)

Comment: Doing this causes the error to go away however the modal does not appear.

Comment: You have data-target set to myModal but the id on the modal as addModal.... they need to match to find the target

Comment: Dillon is right here. **data-target** attribute of button should have same value as that of modal ID.

Comment: I made the change to the data-target and still the modal does not appear.  No errors in the console.

Comment: If these are two seperate html pages they need to be rendered at the same time.  The modal has to be available on the page already for the JQuery version.

Comment: Great that did it!  Thank you.  For some reason the screen behind the modal does not dim and show a dark transparency.  The modal also does not spawn in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap requires Jquery for its widgets to work.  If you want angular versions I would look into angular ui bootstrap here: [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: I am currently using jqwidgets, jqxgrid specfically.  So I am using the Angular Grid component.  I assumed I would create the modal using bootstrap, but I guess that is not the correct way to about it?

Comment: That is fine if you choose to do it that way, you will need to add jquery reference to your html.  But to take advantage of angularjs scope, controllers, databinding, etc... I would recommend using anuglar UI modals.  If you're going to be doing more than a couple I would definitely recommend learning them as they are much easier to use and manipulate data when using angularjs

Comment: Thank you for that feedback.  I will look into it.  My confusion is coming from the fact that the project contains ts files instead of js.  I am new and still learning so learning how to use multiple frameworks together is something I need to get used to.

Comment: Reviewing your code I see you're using angular, not angularJS.  They have libraries for this as well such as ng-bootstrap.

Comment: ts (typescript) files are a superset of js.  They are transpiled into js either at or before runtime.  Jquery is just an external library that bootstrap requires to run its componenents.  It was written in js so it doesn't need to transpile.  But either way is still required for bootstrap widgets to work.

Comment: On top of creating that modal, I also have to link pages to each other by glyph button I guess I would apply the same? using angular ui buttons?

Comment: Buttons are usually just css unless they do something special (like operate as checkbox on/off).  So there usually isn't a need.